# Parse API functions autocomplete is not working in Xcode 7.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, xcode7-beta2

I am using Xcode 7.0 and integrated latest Parse API.
When I start coding in the Xcode editor, it is not suggesting the available functions in the respective object.
For example:
    var query = PFUser.query()

when i type query, it is not showing any functions which are available.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try downloading the Parse SDK Framework and using that? Sometimes, if you're missing some type of linking, it will not work. Also, you can try cleaning and retrying.

Comment: These are the frameworks which I have added
Parse.framework
ParseCrashReporting.framework
Bolts.framework
ParseUI.framework
AudioToolbox.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
libz.1.dylib
libsqlite3.dylib

Comment: did you import <Parse/Parse.h>?